# Notes/Domino : Submit button is not shown in the customized search form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I found steps to customize Notes Web search form but the submission button in the search form is not shown. In the below question, questioner also says the same thing. He seemed it was solved but did not write the cause.
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/0/cad751696e7486ef852571d300478a5c?OpenDocument

Perhaps I have a mistake something but I'm not idea how to solve this. Please advise me!

Comment: Have you checked the hide-when properties for the paragraph containing the button that you added to the form?

Comment: There's also the database property "Use JavaScript when generating pages."  If that box is checked, then Domino will not render a sumbit button.

Comment: Thanks for suggetton. The issue is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old-style web forms are often very difficult to handle in Domino. Luckily there's something much better, really: XPages. If you have a fairly recent server, R9.0.x or better, try to make a simple XPage:

1. Create a new XPage
2. Add a Edit Box from the Core Controls (don't worry about the layout)
3. In the Properties, set the Data to Advanced/Use Scoped Variable, viewScope, and type a name, e.g. ftquery
4. Add a View from the list of Container controls
5. Select an existing view from the current database
6. In the View/Data Properties, set Search in view results to Computed, EL and viewScope.ftquery
7. Attach the Pager to the viewPanel...

Here's a sample, you can paste it in the Source tab of the new XPages and modify it to your liking.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:label value="FT Query" id="label1" for="inputText1"></xp:label>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{viewScope.ftquery}">
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1" for="viewPanel1"></xp:pager>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="Put-here-your-view" search="#{viewScope.ftquery}"></xp:dominoView>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="$2" id="viewColumn1">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="$2" id="viewColumnHeader1"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="Tournament" id="viewColumn2">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Name" id="viewColumnHeader2"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
    </xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

Don't forget to enable Full-Text search on your database!

The XPage can be opened from a browser using http;//yoursite/database.nsf/your-xpage.xsp